# What's the name of argument to pass to action? (argparse)

Tags: python, argparse

```
start_check_stop = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
start_check_stop.add_argument('-s', '--start', action=start(*what*))
start_check_stop.add_argument('-c', '--check', action=check(*what*))
start_check_stop.add_argument('-t', '--stop', action=stop(*what*))
```

What do I need to pass in the spot labeled *what* in order to pass the given command line argument to the function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your action should extend the `argparse.Action` class which already has variable for passing the argument values. The parameter in your action call is unnecessary.

Comment: So I have to create a whole class just to handle each of those actions?

Comment: Yes, if you choose to use the `action=` mechanism. Check out http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#action for a good example of how it works.